# Getting distinct and ordered members from a list of strings - linq or hashset for unique which one is faster / better suited

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, hashset

I have a big list of strings (about 5k-20k entries) that I need to order and also to remove duplicates from.

I've done this in 2 ways now, once with a hashset and once solely with linq. Tests with that number of entries did not show a big difference but I'm wondering what way and thus what method would be better suited.

For the ways (myList is of the datatype List):

**Linq:** I'm using 1 linq statement to order the list and get the distinct values from it.

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(q => q).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Hashset:** I'm using hashset to remove all duplicates and then I'm ordering the list

```
myList = new HashSet<String>(myList).ToList<String>();
myList = myList.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
```

Like I said tests I made were about the same time consumption for both methods but I'm still wondering if one method is better than the other and if so why (the code is for a high performance part and I need to get every millisecond I can out of it).

Comment: "Tests with that number of entries did not show a big difference" - do you expect (vastly) different numbers of entries in the forseeable future? For what it's worth, I think the `Linq` statement looks more readable. Maybe first `Distinct()`, then `OrderBy()`.

Comment: I'm calculating with about 10 times my current numbers as complete max. same here for the linq statement being better readable.

Comment: Can you extrapolate your test data for example by adding `"1"` through `"9"` at start (or end) of every string?

Comment: What about using `SortedSet<String>` it is unique and sorted by default? - See [**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1O06kn). - I don't know if this is faster than sorting after adding the items but maybe you could add it to your tests and check.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl seems to have a relatively similar performance (similar variation in time)

Comment: @Thomas: If they all perform similar/same the choice might be more based on using the right type for the right job. If `SortedSet<string>` does what you need it might be a good choice instead of using LINQ on top?

Answer (score 7):

If you're really concerned about every nanosecond, then

```
myList = myList.Distinct().OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
```

might be slightly faster than:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(q => q).Distinct().ToList();
```

if there are a large number of duplicates.

The LINQ method is more readable and will have similar performance to explicitly creating a `HashSet<T>` as others have said.  In fact it may be slightly faster if the original List is already sorted, since the LINQ method will preserve the initial order before sorting, while explicitly creating a `HashSet<T>` will enumerate in an undefined order.

Answer (score 0):

They are pretty much the same. `Distinct` also uses a `Set<T>` to eliminate duplicates. My suggestion is use the `Distinct` first then sort your items. Also in your second code, `ToList<String>` call is redundant, you can use `OrderBy` on `HashSet` then call `ToList`.

Comment: Good point there tnx. So in effect it doesnt matter which method of the two to use as both go the same way (in my tests I have a strong variance for each attempt regardless of method used it can take 1.4-2.3 seconds which made it nearly impossible to tell if one of the two is actually faster or not).